# Is it safe to run in-process migrations from an application running on multiple servers?

Tags: fluent-migrator

The FluentMigrator documentation [recommends running migrations in-process upon application start](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/quickstart.html?tabs=runner-in-process), but I don't see any commentary about whether this is safe or recommended when the application is running on multiple servers.

I have always gone the paranoid route of using an out-of-process runner before deploying my applications by triggering it from my build servers. Is that paranoia warranted? Will the [Transaction-Per-Migration](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/migration/migration-transaction-behavior.html) defaults be enough to guarantee that no migration conflicts can occur on the same codebase trying to run simultaneous upgrade migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, this functionality is not yet supported and the [documentation](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/quickstart.html?tabs=runner-in-process) has been updated to recommend an out-of-process migration runner when your application is run from multiple processes.

There is currently an [issue on Github](https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator/issues/996) requesting this feature as well as a workaround specifically for SQL Server 2008+ using [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).